# My scrapy code is working at debug mode but not working

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrape

So my code is not working.But I tried on debug mode it worked.Whats wrong with my code?

```
from email import header
from requests import request
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
import time

class ArabalarSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'arabalar'
    allowed_domains = ['sahibinden.com']
    
    
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url = 'https://www.sahibinden.com/otomobil', headers={
            'User-Agent' : self.user_agent
        } )


    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//tbody[@class='searchResultsRowClass']/tr/td[5]/a[1]"), callback='parse_item', follow=True,process_request='set_user_agent'),
    )
    def set_user_agent(self,request,spider):
        request.headers['User-Agent'] = self.user_agent
    def parse_item(self, response):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        yield{
            'Başlık' : response.xpath(".//div[@class='classifiedDetailTitle']/h1/text()").get(),
            'Marka'  : response.xpath(".//ul[@class='classifiedInfoList']/li[3]/span/text()").get(),
            'Seri'   : response.xpath(".//ul[@class='classifiedInfoList']/li[4]/span/text()").get(),
            'Yakıt Türü'  : response.xpath(".//ul[@class='classifiedInfoList']/li[7]/span/text()").get(),
            'Vites'       : response.xpath(".//ul[@class='classifiedInfoList']/li[8]/span/text()").get(),
            'KM'          : response.xpath(".//ul[@class='classifiedInfoList']/li[10]/span/text()").get(),
            'Araç Durumu' : response.xpath(".//ul[@class='classifiedInfoList']/li[9]/span/text()").get(),
            'Satıcı İsmi' : response.xpath("//div[@class='classifiedOtherBoxes ']/div/div[2]/div[2]/h5/text()").get(),
            'Telefon'     : response.xpath("//div[@class='classifiedOtherBoxes ']/div/div[2]/ul/li/span[1]/text()").get(),
            'User-Agent'  : response.request.headers['User-Agent']
            


 
        }
```

I tried to scrape a  website.

Comment: what do you mean it's not working?  please provide any error message, logs, or describe what happens when you run the code and how you run the code